# Mail "Can't continue" for a AppleScript function

Tags: email, applescript

I'm trying to write an AppleScript for use with Mail (on Snow Leopard) to save image attachments of messages to a folder.  The main part of the AppleScript is:

```
property ImageExtensionList : {"jpg", "jpeg"}
property PicturesFolder : path to pictures folder as text
property SaveFolderName : "Fetched"
property SaveFolder : PicturesFolder & SaveFolderName

tell application "Mail"
  set theMessages to the selection
  repeat with theMessage in theMessages
    repeat with theAttachment in every mail attachment of theMessage
      set attachmentFileName to theAttachment's name
      if isImageFileName(attachmentFileName) then
        set attachmentPathName to SaveFolder & attachmentFileName
        save theAttachment in getNonexistantFile(attachmentPathName)
      end if        
    end repeat
  end repeat
end tell

on isImageFileName(theFileName)
  set dot to offset of "." in theFileName
  if dot > 0 then
    set theExtension to text (dot + 1) thru -1 of theFileName
    return theExtension is in ImageExtensionList
  end if
  return false
end isImageFileName
```

When run, I get the error:

> error "Mail got an error: Can’t continue isImageFileName." number -1708

where error -1708 is:

> Event wasnt handled by an Apple event handler.

However, if I copy/paste the `isImageFileName()` into another script like:

```
property ImageExtensionList : {"jpg", "jpeg"}

on isImageFileName(theFileName)
  set dot to offset of "." in theFileName
  if dot > 0 then
    set theExtension to text (dot + 1) thru -1 of theFileName
    return theExtension is in ImageExtensionList
  end if
  return false
end isImageFileName

if isImageFileName("foo.jpg") then
  return true
else
  return false
end if
```

it works fine.  Why does Mail complain about this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try "my isImageFileName".  It's not Mail, just a quirk of AppleScript.

Comment: Note that `my` should be added at the place of call, so that `isImageFileName` resolves from outside the tell block.

Answer (score 38):

It may be a quirk, but it has an explanation. If you're in a `tell application "whatever"` block, all calls are made in the namespace of that application's dictionary, not your script's dictionary. Because of that, you have to explicity tell AppleScript to look back into your script for the name. Saying `my` is like saying `tell me`, instructing the script where to look for the function.

Comment: In other words it is a namespacing and scope issue. Excellent.

Comment: I hope at some point as I keep learning applescript, such things will quit taking disproportionate time :)
At this point it feels like I have to write many more lines in AS for comparable functionality of other languages.